# Azure pipeline MsBuild parameter/property define constant not working for precompiling directive

Tags: .net, azure, compilation, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a build step with a build directive parameter, so that we can decide, inside a class, which code to use depending on the precompiler directive. It works when building on my local machine, but not when building with Azure Pipelines.

Here is a example I've created:

The project .csproj has nothing in particular:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The class using the build directive:

```
namespace TestCompilingDirective;

public class TestCompileDirective
{
        static int i = 1;

        public static void Init()
        {
#if DO_LOG_ADDRESS
                i = 10;
# endif
        }
}
```

Compiling locally with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\src\MySolution.sln" /p:DefineConstants="DO_LOG_ADDRESS"
```

The resulting compiled code locally:
[image]

The pipeline build task:

```
  - task: MSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '$(SolutionDir)/*.sln'
      msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
      msbuildArguments: '/p:Configuration=Release /p:DefineConstants="DO_LOG_ADDRESS" /verbosity:diagnostic'
```

On the pipeline logs, we can verify that the directive is being applied:
[image]

However, the resulting compiled code does not include the code inside the directive check:
[image]

Notes:

- MSBuild version = "17.6.3+07e294721"
- I've tried `dotnet build`, same
  problem

Comment: Is the behavior different if you build the project directly (instead of building via the sln)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried also building directly the .csproj and some behavior, works on local but it doesnt work on azure pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create one build directive in a sample console app like below:-

I have set the `DO_LOG_ADDRESS` value to `true` in my pipeline variable like below:-

[image]

Ran the YAML Script below:-

```yaml
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Set Environment Variable'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DO_LOG_ADDRESS;isOutput=true]$(DO_LOG_ADDRESS)"

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '/p:Configuration=Release'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

In order to resolve your error, Try changing the configuration in Azure Pipelines to Release instead of debug where DO_LOG_ADDRESS is not defined.

Check the Build logs by enabling Enable Diagnostic settings and verify if there are any failures.

Usually, If the Directive is showing applied in the Logs, The same is not reflected in the Code in your Azure repository.

Try to rebuild your solution by the task below:-

```yaml
- task: Clean@2
  inputs:
    cleanFolders: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
```